# How can I add a Path, that has been defined in the XAML ResourceDictionary, multiple times to a WPF form at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a defined path in XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Path x:Key="N44" Width="20" Height="80" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="M 20,25.2941L 20,29.4118L 15.9091,29.4118L 15.9091,40L 12.2727,40L 12.2727,29.4118L 2.54313e-006,29.4118L 2.54313e-006,25.6985L 13.4872,7.62939e-006L 15.9091,7.62939e-006L 15.9091,25.2941L 20,25.2941 Z M 12.2727,25.2941L 12.2727,5.28493L 2.09517,25.2941L 12.2727,25.2941 Z M 20,65.2941L 20,69.4118L 15.9091,69.4118L 15.9091,80L 12.2727,80L 12.2727,69.4118L -5.08626e-006,69.4118L -5.08626e-006,65.6985L 13.4872,40L 15.9091,40L 15.9091,65.2941L 20,65.2941 Z M 12.2727,65.2941L 12.2727,45.2849L 2.09517,65.2941L 12.2727,65.2941 Z "/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I want to add it to a WPF Gird & doing it once like this works:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Path aPath = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
aPath = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)this.Resources["N44"];
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(aPath);
```

However if I add this code on a button click event and then click the button twice, an error is thrown stating

> "Specified Visual is already a child
>   of another Visual or the root of a
>   CompositionTarget."

I then attempted to create two instances of the resource but I have continued to receive the same error. Below is the code that I used for this test:

```
private void cmbTest_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   System.Windows.Shapes.Path aPath = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
   aPath = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)this.Resources["N44"];

   if (LayoutRoot.Children.Contains(aPath) == true){
    System.Windows.Shapes.Path bPath = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)this.Resources["N44"];
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(bPath); 
   }else{
    aPath.Name = "a";
    aPath.Tag = "a";
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(aPath);
   }
  }
```

As such, how can I add an XAML Path, which has been defined in the ResourceDictionary, multiple times to a WPF form at runtime?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've since found that I had missed an important part of the [documentation from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary(VS.95).aspx):

> Shareable Types and UIElement Types:
>
> A resource dictionary is a technique for
>   defining shareable types and values of
>   these types in XAML. Not all types or
>   values are suitable for usage from a
>   ResourceDictionary. For more
>   information on which types are
>   considered shareable in Silverlight,
>   see Resource Dictionaries.
>
> In particular, all UIElement derived
>   types are not shareable unless they
>   come from templates and application of
>   a template on a specific control
>   instance. Excluding the template case,
>   a UIElement is expected to only exist
>   in one place in an object tree once
>   instantiated, and having a UIElement
>   be shareable would potentially violate
>   this principle.

Which I will summarise as, that's not the way it works because **it’s not creating a new instance** each time I execute that code – it’s only creating a reference to the object – which is why it works once but not multiple times. 
So after a bit more reading I’ve come up with 3 potential ways for a resolution to my problem.

**1)** Use a technique to create a deep copy to a new object. Example from other StackOverflow Question - [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)

**2)** Store the XAML in strings within the application and then use the XAML reader to create instances of the Paths:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Path newPath = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse("<Path xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'  Width='20' Height='80' Stretch='Fill' Fill='#FF000000' Data='M 20,25.2941L 20,29.4118L 15.9091,29.4118L 15.9091,40L 12.2727,40L 12.2727,29.4118L 2.54313e-006,29.4118L 2.54313e-006,25.6985L 13.4872,7.62939e-006L 15.9091,7.62939e-006L 15.9091,25.2941L 20,25.2941 Z M 12.2727,25.2941L 12.2727,5.28493L 2.09517,25.2941L 12.2727,25.2941 Z M 20,65.2941L 20,69.4118L 15.9091,69.4118L 15.9091,80L 12.2727,80L 12.2727,69.4118L -5.08626e-006,69.4118L -5.08626e-006,65.6985L 13.4872,40L 15.9091,40L 15.9091,65.2941L 20,65.2941 Z M 12.2727,65.2941L 12.2727,45.2849L 2.09517,65.2941L 12.2727,65.2941 Z ' HorizontalAlignment='Left' VerticalAlignment='Top' Margin='140,60,0,0'/>");
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(newPath);
```

**3)** Only store the Path data in the Resource Dictionary. Create a new instance of a Path in code, apply the Path data to the new Path and then add the other properties I am interested in manually.

The XAML - The Path data is stored as a StreamGeometry:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="N44">M 20,25.2941L 20,29.4118L 15.9091,29.4118L 15.9091,40L 12.2727,40L 12.2727,29.4118L 2.54313e-006,29.4118L 2.54313e-006,25.6985L 13.4872,7.62939e-006L 15.9091,7.62939e-006L 15.9091,25.2941L 20,25.2941 Z M 12.2727,25.2941L 12.2727,5.28493L 2.09517,25.2941L 12.2727,25.2941 Z M 20,65.2941L 20,69.4118L 15.9091,69.4118L 15.9091,80L 12.2727,80L 12.2727,69.4118L -5.08626e-006,69.4118L -5.08626e-006,65.6985L 13.4872,40L 15.9091,40L 15.9091,65.2941L 20,65.2941 Z M 12.2727,65.2941L 12.2727,45.2849L 2.09517,65.2941L 12.2727,65.2941 Z</StreamGeometry>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The C# code to then create an instance and apply the other values:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Path bPath = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
bPath.Data = (System.Windows.Media.Geometry)this.FindResource("N44");

bPath.Width = 20;
bPath.Height = 80;

bPath.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
bPath.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

left = left + 40;

System.Windows.Thickness thickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(left,100,0,0);
bPath.Margin = thickness;

bPath.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(bPath);
```

Comment: Storing the Path.Data as a StreamGeometry in a Resource is brilliant!

Answer (score 15):

There's an easier, built-in way to do this.
Set x:Shared="False" on the resource. This will allow it to be reused. Then use it as many times as you want.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Path x:Shared="False" x:Key="N44" Width="20" Height="80" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="..."/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create style for Path, and apply it.

Comment: this is the best clean advice to use because you'll remember this solution for similar scenarios in cross platform xaml.