# WinRT Binding compact path markup (a string resource) to Path Data

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-runtime

***My goal***: I want to create a reusable UserControl called `DynamicButton` (reusable within this app, I don't need to use it in different projects) which displays 3 different shapes. Each instance of the button will have a different set of 3 shapes.

I've tried to define the Path shapes separately so they can be reused (I'll use Path1 in a DynamicButton on multiple Pages). I've been through a couple iterations trying to find something that works. At first I just tried to define the paths as resources and then pass those resources to my `DynamicButton` class so they could be added to the button's internal Grid, but it wouldn't work because the Path object was already considered to be elsewhere in the view hierarchy so it wouldn't let me put it into the `DynamicButton`'s view hierarchy. (see [WinRT XAML trying to use a Path defined in ResourceDictionary, but "Element is already the child of another element."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480086/winrt-xaml-trying-to-use-a-path-defined-in-resourcedictionary-but-element-is-a) for details).

So, then I decided to try to generate my paths using the compact shape markup syntax shown below. I figured I would just pass that as a string into my `DynamicButton` code and then I could use that string to programmatically create the Path. However, it doesn't appear there is anyway to give that compact syntax to a Path object in code. It only works in XAML.

Now I'm trying to use a templated control with bindings to try to get the shape path markup into the Path object.

I've got a string defined which includes the compact Path markup syntax to describe a shape:

```
<x:String x:Key="ShapeView_N">M 131.12,10.6 L 141.17,10.6 L 141.17,85.34 L 132.07,85.34 L 82.68,27.78 L 82.68,85.34 L 72.74,85.34 L 72.74,10.6 L 81.31,10.6 L 131.12,68.65 L 131.12,10.6 L 131.12,10.6</x:String>
```

I want to pass that to my custom UserControl (DynamicButton) so that my control can create a Path with it.

```
<local:DynamicButton x:Name="MyButton" 
    ShapeString="{StaticResource ShapeView_N}" 
/>
```

In the template for my `DynamicButton`, I have code like this:

```
<Path x:Name="PathWhite" Data="{TemplateBinding ShapeString}" Fill="White" />
```

If I put that ShapeView_N string directly into the Data attribute for a Path, that would be perfectly valid xaml and would compile just fine. Like this:

```
<Path x:Name="PathWhite" Data="M 131.12,10.6 L 141.17,10.6 L 141.17,85.34 L 132.07,85.34 L 82.68,27.78 L 82.68,85.34 L 72.74,85.34 L 72.74,10.6 L 81.31,10.6 L 131.12,68.65 L 131.12,10.6 L 131.12,10.6" Fill="White" />
```

However, when I try to get it put there using the TemplateBinding, my app crashes because `Data` expects a `Path` object instead of a `string`. :( However, if I put a string literal into `Data` in my xaml, that works just fine.

I feel like this shouldn't be THIS hard. I have some Path data. I want to have a custom UserControl which accepts 3 Paths in SOME format.. ANY format will do.

Help?

Comment: you can use the `x:Shared="false" attribute on the resource, Path you want to share across multiple controls.

Comment: It looks like x:Shared is only available for WPF, but this is a Windows App Store app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`StringToPathGeometryConverter`](https://stringtopathgeometry.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PathConverter/PathConverter/StringToPathGeometryConverter.cs) to convert your strings to geometries, but I'd use a `DataTemplate` instead. You would define `DataTemplate` resources that have a `Path` element in them with the geometry specified, then use these as `ContentTemplate` values of your buttons.